# How to remove all <link> tags between two <meta> tags using Javascript (not Jquery)?

Tags: javascript, html

This is how certain external css files are placed between two meta tags.

```
<meta id="front-template-css-anchor-start" name="front-template-css-anchor-start" content="This is where front template css will be added"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/LineIcons.2.0.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/animate.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/tiny-slider.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/glightbox.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/main.css" />
<meta id="front-template-css-anchor-end" name="front-template-css-anchor-end" content="This is where front template css will be added"/>
```

In my js code, I tried to get the two meta tags like this:-

```
var frontTemplateCssAnchorStart       = document.querySelector('#front-template-css-anchor-start');
var frontTemplateCssAnchorEnd         = document.querySelector('#front-template-css-anchor-end');
```

This code,

```
frontTemplateCssAnchorEnd.previousElementSibling.remove();
```

removes `<link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/main.css" />` from the DOM. But I want to iterate from `frontTemplateCssAnchorStart` to `frontTemplateCssAnchorEnd` and delete/remove all `<link>` tags. But I am stuck and don't know how to proceed from here.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the `nextElementSibling`s until the end element is reached.

```js
for (let curr = frontTemplateCssAnchorStart.nextElementSibling, next; 
        curr && curr != frontTemplateCssAnchorEnd; curr = next) {
    next = curr.nextElementSibling;
    if (curr.matches('link')) curr.remove();
}
```

Comment: Wow! That was a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a ***[`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)*** property and iterate through the siblings. Something like:

```js
let currentEl = frontTemplateCssAnchorStart.nextElementSibling;

while (currentEl && currentEl !== frontTemplateCssAnchorEnd) {
  let nextEl = currentEl.nextElementSibling;
  if (currentEl.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'link') {
    currentEl.remove();
  }
  currentEl = nextEl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice simple one liner

```
document.querySelectorAll('#front-template-css-anchor-start ~ link:not(#front-template-css-anchor-end ~ link)').forEach(link => link.remove());
```

Demo with spans

```js
document.querySelectorAll('#front-template-css-anchor-start ~ span:not(#front-template-css-anchor-end ~ span)').forEach(link => link.remove());
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<meta id="front-template-css-anchor-start" name="front-template-css-anchor-start" content="This is where front template css will be added"/>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<meta id="front-template-css-anchor-end" name="front-template-css-anchor-end" content="This is where front template css will be added"/>
<span>4</span>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/front-template/assets/css/main.css" />
```